# Output recent posts and excerpt in Wordpress, not of current page

Tags: php, wordpress, posts

I am trying to output recent posts plus the excerpt onto my homepage using the following code:

```
<?php
        $args = array( 'numberposts' => '3' );
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="Look '.$recent["post_title"].'" >' .   $recent["post_title"].'</a>' . $recent["post_excerpt"] . ' </li> ';
    }
?>
```

This seems to output the title and the permalink just fine, however it does not output the excerpt.

Hope someone can help

Answer (score 2):

put the array in your desired custom post like this in your `functions.php`

```
$args = array(
      'supports' => array('title','editor','author','excerpt') // by writing these lines an custom field  has been added to CMS
  );
```

For retrieving at front end

```
echo $post->post_excerpt; // this will return you the excerpt of the current post
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
<?php
        $args = array( 'post_type'=>'post',
'orderby'=>'post_date',
'post_status'=>'publish', 
'order'           => 'DESC',
'showposts' => '3' );
    $recent_posts = get_posts( $args );
    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($recent->ID) . '" title="Look '.$recent->post_title.'" >' .   $recent->post_title.'</a>' . $recent->post_excerpt . ' </li> ';
    }
?>
```

Make sure your `post_excerpt` is not empty

If you want to add the `post_excerpt` then use `wp_update_post`

```
  $my_post = array();
  $my_post['ID'] = 37;// it is important
  $my_post['post_excerpt'] = 'This is the updated post excerpt.';


  wp_update_post( $my_post );
```

As per your request in comments i am showing you the demo to update the `post` by  copying the `post_title` in the `post_excerpt` so here you go

```
<?php
        $args = array( 'post_type'=>'post',
'orderby'=>'post_date',
'post_status'=>'publish', 
'order'           => 'DESC',
'showposts' => '3' );
    $recent_posts = get_posts( $args );

    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){  // this foreach to add the excerpt
            $my_post = array();
  $my_post['ID'] = $recent->ID;// it is important
  $my_post['post_excerpt'] = $recent->post_content;    
  wp_update_post( $my_post );
    }

    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){  // this foreach to show the excerpt
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($recent->ID) . '" title="Look '.$recent->post_title.'" >' .   $recent->post_title.'</a>' . $recent->post_excerpt . ' </li> ';
    }
?>
```

[wp_update_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post)

Also see [wp_insert_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post)

Comment: This still doesn't output any excerpt. Can you explain to me how to make the excerpt not "empty"? I thought the excerpt was just truncated post content.

Comment: var_dump($recent_posts); see whats in it

Comment: Could you explain how one would use wp_update_post within the code you posted above? This is the part I am finding most difficult to get working, I cannot get the excerpt to display.

Comment: Thanks but the code provided still does not provide an excerpt.